# Is it possible to put logos on the y-axis

Tags: r, image, plotly, yaxis

I have a very simple plotly graph for which I would like to put the company logos instead (or both) of their names on the Y axis

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(
  y = c("company_1", "company_2", "company_3", "company_4", "company_5"),
  x = c(20, 14, 23, 6, 28),
  name = "companies",
  type = "bar"
)
```

For example, we can imagine that the companies are Facebook, Twitter, Apple, Microsoft and Tesla
I have images (logo) in png format.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [there](https://plotly.com/r/images/) is an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something you'll be able to do strictly in R. However, if you use the function `onRender` from `htmlwidgets`, you can do it.

I added `margin` so the images would fit. However, the plot is exactly as you provided it. Make sure that if/when you make changes you respect the whitespace shown here. HTML and Javascript won't understand if the attributes are smashed together.

The first code & plot uses an image that is on the web. The next code & plot uses a local file. That way you can use whichever method applies in your situation.

#### Images via Hyperlink

```
plot_ly(
  y = c("company_1", "company_2", "company_3", "company_4", "company_5"),
  x = c(20, 14, 23, 6, 28),
  name = "companies",
  type = "bar") %>% 
  layout(margin = list(l = 120, r = 20, t = 20, b = 50)) %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender("function(){
    gimme = document.querySelectorAll('g.ytick');   /* get the text positions on y-axis */
    imTag1 = '<image width=\"100\" height=\"100\" ' /* pre-build the HTML */
    imTag2 = ' href=\"https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/RStudio-Logo-Flat.png\" />'
    for(i = 0; i < gimme.length; i++) {
      zz = gimme[i].firstChild.getAttribute('transform'); /* get position on page*/
      yy = gimme[i].firstChild.getAttribute('y');
      yy = yy * -10;
      img = imTag1 + 'x=\"10\" y=\"' + yy + '\" transform=\"' + zz + '\"' + imTag2;
      gimme[i].innerHTML = img;    /* replace the text tag */
    } 
  }")
```

[image]

#### Images via Local File

The image I used here is from https://www.hiclipart.com/free-transparent-background-png-clipart-qzdon/download

In MY files it's saved at ./_images/orangeIcon.png (where '.' represents the current working directory).

Because this file is a png, I need to make something better for web portability, so I used base64 encoding using the package `base64enc`.

```
img <- base64enc::dataURI(file = "./_images/orangeIcon.png")
```

I'm going to assign this to `customdata` in the call for `plotly`. If you had five images, you can make a list of the 5 encoded images. if you list one, `plotly` will replicate it. (That's what it did here.)

```
plot_ly(
  y = c("company_1", "company_2", "company_3", "company_4", "company_5"),
  x = c(20, 14, 23, 6, 28),
  name = "companies", customdata = img,       # <---- custom data!!
  type = "bar") %>% 
  layout(margin = list(l = 120, r = 20, t = 20, b = 50)) %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender("function(el, x){      /* changed here, as well */
        gimme = document.querySelectorAll('g.ytick');   /* get the text positions on y-axis */
        imgs = x.data[0].customdata;           /* collect the images */
        imTag1 = '<image width=\"100\" height=\"100\" href=\"' /* pre-build the HTML */
        imTag2 = ' \" />'
        for(i = 0; i < gimme.length; i++) {
          zz = gimme[i].firstChild.getAttribute('transform'); /* get position on page*/
          yy = gimme[i].firstChild.getAttribute('y');
          yy = yy * -10;
          img = imTag1 + imgs[i] + '\" x=\"10\" y=\"' + yy + '\" transform=\"' + zz + '\"' + imTag2;
          gimme[i].innerHTML = img;    /* replace the text tag */
        } 
      }") # note the differences in imgTag1 and imgTag2 
          #             to accommodate the new info for href
```

[image]